# For Each Next loop getting first row data only

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to populate a dataset with data from a dynamic SQL dataset created by a code generator (PDSA). If I want the first row of data, or I use a specific "Where" clause to retrieve 1 row, I have no problem. But, when I loop through the dataset that has four entries, instead of getting the four entries, I get the first row 4 times. Any idea why?

Code Example:

```
Dim DS_C as New DS
Dim dr_A As DS_C.Tbl_ARow               

    Me.DS_C.Tbl_A.Clear()

    Dim bo As PDSA.DataLayer.tbl_BDC = New PDSA.BusinessLayer.tbl_B

    With bo
        .ConnectionString = AppConfig.SQLConnectString
        .SelectFilter = PDSA.DataLayer.tbl_BDC.SelectFilters.All
        .WhereFilter = tbl_BDC.WhereFilters.None
        .Load()
    End With        

    For Each dr As DataRow In bo.DataSet.Tables(0).Rows

        dr_A = DS_C.Tbl_A.NewRow

        With dr_A
            .CustomerID = bo.CustomerID
            .FirstName = bo.FirstName
            .LastName = bo.LastName
            .Street = bo.Street
            .City = bo.City
            .State = bo.State
            .ZipCode = bo.ZipCode
        End With

        DS_C.Tbl_A.AddTbl_ARow(dr_A)

    Next
```

If I try to change it to use dr instead of bo , it wont accept it.

I get:

```
.CustomerID = dr.CustomerID(CustomerID is not a member of System.Data.DataRow)
```

If I try using `DS_C.Tbl_ARow`

```
For Each dr As DS_C.Tbl_ARow In bo.DataSet.Tables(0).Rows
```

I get type 'DS_C.Tbl_ARow' is not defined

If I try :

```
For Each dr As DS.Tbl_ARow In bo.DataSet.Tables(0).Rows
```

I get:

```
System.InvalidCastException = {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRow' to type 'TblXLMajorPerilsRow'."}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access it like this:

```
.CustomerID = dr("CustomerID");
```

Comment: A much more concise way of saying it.  +1 to you.

Comment: And since we’re in VB: `.CustomerID = dr("CustomerID")`

Comment: @Mrchief And while we’re on it, VB actually also allows the syntax `.CustomerID = dr!CustomerID` but I believe the current consensus is that this syntax be avoided. Anyway, +1.